# Vscode debugger detaches from process after using attach by process id

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to get the vscode debugger to stop at breakpoints for my program that I run from the vscode terminal.

Setting `Debug › JavaScript: Auto Attach Filter` to `always`has no effect on this.

I am able to get the debugger to stop at breakpoints if I click `Attach by Process Id` and then select my process from the vscode dropdown

[image]

During another process though (`npm run build`) the debugger keeps detaching as you can see in the gif below

[image]

I would like the debugger to stop at the breakpoints that I set